# Market modelling with prosumers

Tags: reference-request, energy-economics

I am working on energy integration modelling in a system with prosumers. I was wondering if there is any well-known theory or model in the economics literature for markets (specially multi-commodity merkets) where market's players can be producer and consumer at the same time.